# Lotus Notes auto export

Tags: lotus-notes

I am doing trend analysis of data from lotus notes. I need to manually export data from lotus notes and import it into excel. Is there a way to automate this? I can even work with Access. I tried to create an agent and I do not have access to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, depending on your skills and your access to the Notes database.
First of all, when you say "I do not have access to [create an agent]", are you saying that you don't have designer access to the database where the data lives?

If that is the case, simply build a separate Notes application, and write your export agent there. Put that application on the same server, and you can set the export to run every night 8or whenever you like).

Another option is to use COM in Access and pull the data over that way. You have all the COM classes documnented in the Domino Designer help, and the code should be very similar to what you would writ in Lotusscript.

A third option, if the database is web enabled, is to use HTTP to pull the data out of views. You can read it using ?ReadViewEntries, either as XML or as JSON. This requires that all the data you need is exposed in the view, though.

I think the first option is the best, though. However, if you have been tasked with creating this export, you should be able to ask for proper access to the database...

Comment: I like the first option, If I go this route would I need to manually import the data into excel or access? And how do I go about creating a separate notes application.

Comment: Open Domino Designer, then do File, New, Application... to create it. Then just create your agent there.
On the question "would I need to manually import the data into excel or access", the answer is "it depends". It depends on the code you write. You can export the data as files (CSV, XML, or whatever tet format you like), or you can use COM to create Excel spreadsheets or (probably) populate Access databases with the data. It's up to you...
But I would imagine the easiest would be for you to just create a CSV file...

Comment: Here are links to some articles on my blog that might help you:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-from-notes-to-excel-3-different-ways/ and http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/ Hope they help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a past posting, but someone may need the latest answers get to Domino Data.

1. You can export any view in Notes.  File -> Export -> Select CSV as the option.
2. Then there is the IBM ODBC driver.  There are two versions.  One for 8.5.3 and another for 9.x.  Download here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/toolkits.html

Instructions on how to install here http://xpagesbeast.com/uxdesign/dont-forget-about-the-notessql-driver/

3. Using DomSQL which is a true JDBC driver for Notes Domino data. Non Notes environments can execute SQL SELECT queries using this JDBC driver.
   http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8Q7AW3
4. Using the Domino REST Services.  You can access DominoData through a URL and it returns JSON.  There are URLs to get all database instances on the server, then you can get all views in the server, and you can then access documents in the views.
   http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create an agent (no designer access) you can try to install NotesSQL (ODBC driver) besides your Notes Client and access with Excel, MsQuery, etc. with your user id.

You can find more information here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/